Linked Server Using current security context SSMS ver 20.2 fails
Trying to figure out why I'm getting a Login failed for user 'NT Authority\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error when creating a Linked server using SSMS ver 20.2.
Some preliminary information:
I have sysAdmin on both servers.
I'm using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver.
I'm setting security to "Be made using the  login's current security context:"
SQLServer2019.
My DBA coworker is able to create the linked server and use it with out issue.  Only difference we have is he is on an older version of SSMS.
If I tell SQL Server to create the Linked server in spite of the error my coworker can use the linked server but If I try to use it the test connection fails.
Is this a bug in SSMS ver 20.2?

For Kerberos delegation to work you need: the user running SSMS must be a domain user (and not a Protected User/Domain Admin etc); both SQL Server machines must be domain joined (all the same domain as user), and must have the correct SPNs; Constrained Delegation or RBCD must be set up between the two servers; you must connect to the first server using the FQDN not just hostname or IP, and linked server must also use FQDN. Can you confirm all of that?

@Charlieface Both serves are in same domain.  The other DBA who can create the linked server and I have the same privileges.  We performed the linked server creation using TSQL Scripts.  It worked for him but I received the error.  Only difference between him and I is I have most recent version of SSMS.

Are you connecting the same two servers together, ie are the local and linked servers the same? Please show your script, are they identical? Is it the creation of the linked server that's failing, or the connecting to it?
